# Partial view does not Update with ms ajax in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a search text box and a button. I want to show the results of the search in a partial view with ajax when the button is clicked. When I set a break point in the partial view I can see data but nothing shows on the form.

My controller that passes the text value for the search:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchtext)
        {

            // search data and put it in Results here ...
            ViewBag.Results = Results;

            return PartialView("_SearchResults");
        }
```

My index.cshtml view code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="SearchStr" name="SearchStr" placeholder="search" required="required" title="Search" type="search" value="">

    @Html.SubmitButton("Search", "btnSearch")

    <div id="resultsDiv">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "resultsDiv" }))
        {
            <p>hre</p>
        }
    </div>
}


@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#btnSearch").on("click", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                datatype: "json",
                url: "/Home/Index",
                data: {
                    searchtext: document.getElementById("SearchStr").value
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

and this is my partial view that in brek point I can see 51 number of results ..

```
@if (ViewBag.Results != null)
{
    foreach (var person in ViewBag.Results.Data)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                @person.FullName
            </p>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I don't have an error in compile and run time, and no error in the browser ...

I learned this step by step with this video: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5S7Eaw8VhbM)

Comment: Your not doing anything with the html your return. In the ajax function, add `success: function(data) { $(someElement).html(data); }` But you have nested forms which is invalid and not supported so that will be a problem as well

Comment: Where is the `success` setting of your AJAX call?

Comment: i add this and the results : http://picpaste.com/ajax-YCSkpr9K.png agin not load results

Comment: @MoHaMmAd, you have multiple errors in your code. Your method returns html yet you specify `dataType: 'json',` (it needs to be `html`). And remove the nested `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

Comment: you need to cast the ViewBag.Results to the object type that you assign to it

Comment: in break point in line : @person.FullName i can see the name , and when i dont use ajax a can see them on the page

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks , your firs solotion work correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This One

```
    <div id="resultsDiv"> </div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "resultsDiv" }))
    {
        <p>hre</p>
    }
```

## resultsDiv will update after complete ajax call

Also make sure your foreach loop data

```
    foreach (var person in ViewBag.Results.Data)
{
    <div>
        <p>
            @person.FullName
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Have you try this InsertionMode.Replace instead of InsertionMode.InsertAfter ?